# Get the identifier of NSToolbarItem at index

Tags: swift, desktop-application, nstoolbaritem

I implemented a method that adds a toolbar item at index each time the method run.

```
thetoolbar.insertItemWithItemIdentifier("safaributton", atIndex: 3)
```

I must wrap this code that inserts the toolbar item with an if/else, else I get this item repeatedly added to the toolbar when ever the method runs.

```
if ?????? {
    // execute only if the toolbar item with identifier does not already exist.
    thetoolbar.insertItemWithItemIdentifier("safaributton", atIndex: 3)
}
```

I can not find an appropriate way to check the identifier of the current toolbar item at index 3..?

Answer (score 0):

.itemIdentifier as opposed to .identifier

```
if thetoolbar.items[3].itemIdentifier != "safaributton"{
        thetoolbar.insertItemWithItemIdentifier("safaributton", atIndex: 3)
    }
```